# Difference between application framework and a UI framework

Tags: user-interface, frameworks

Discussion actually came as part of a some meeting that there is essentially something that demarcates an application framework and a UI framework.

Is there any?

It will be worthwhile to know if there can be multiple application frameworks in the same projects (I doubt).

It will also be nice if you can help me understand basic definition of the terms.

Apologies if it sounds too naive.

Answer (score 0):

Web UI framework handles HTML generation for your software. You would still need to write business logic and operate with objects, but the interface is abstracted and is not getting in your way.

Here is a good introduction to use of Object for Web Development http://agiletoolkit.org/learn/intro

Another good UI Frameworks are [Sencha](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/) and [Cappuchino](http://cappuccino.org/).